# Access my data structure in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
single_account([('test', ['b"sc\\x00\\x02\\xe2e\\x96\\x99\\xbd\\xd9!R+\\xdf\\x87\\xd6\\xe8\\x9b\\xa8\\xd2q\\x92z\\x8a\\xe6\\xdat\\xd2\\x81\\x0f\\xb4r\\x021\\x0c\\xdd\\x00\\xba\\xe0\\xa8\\x13L\\x17\\xe2.\\xdb\\x9e\\xbe\\x1bE\\x8e\\xfd\\xbd\\xe6?\'\\x08\\x8f&\\xa2\\xf4;\\x93\\xe2\\xb5\\xb3{4\\xe1\\xd8"', "b'sc\\x00\\x02\\x97\\xcb\\x86\\x9f\\x18O\\xca\\xa4\\xd8\\x85\\xbcZ\\xb5 \\xda\\x19\\xc9_\\xf9\\x086\\xbe\\xb4\\x06\\x14\\x1a\\xe2\\x7fH\\xfe\\x19\\xe51\\x02\\x1e\\x83\\xd0\\x97\\xc2QL\\xd6\\xcb\\x13\\x89\\x1b\\x8bhX\\xe1Q\\xac\\x83}?\\xe2\\xc9\\xc4\\x10\\xec\\xeb=\\x96t\\xcc&\\x9d]\\xbdQY\\x95\\xfb\\xd4\\x93\\xc3\\xe1'", "b'\\xa5\\xb2\\xa5\\x99\\x00\\x90\\xdc\\x0e'", 1])])
```

**How can I access the value of:** `"b'\\xa5\\xb2\\xa5\\x99\\x00\\x90\\xdc\\x0e'"`? I know, this seems so seemingly easy, but when i access `single_account[3]`

I get:

```
1
```

If I access `single_account[2]`, i get:

```
"b'sc\\x00\\x02\\x97\\xcb\\x86\\x9f\\x18O\\xca\\xa4\\xd8\\x85\\xbcZ\\xb5 \\xda\\x19\\xc9_\\xf9\\x086\\xbe\\xb4\\x06\\x14\\x1a\\xe2\\x7fH\\xfe\\x19\\xe51\\x02\\x1e\\x83\\xd0\\x97\\xc2QL\\xd6\\xcb\\x13\\x89\\x1b\\x8bhX\\xe1Q\\xac\\x83}?\\xe2\\xc9\\xc4\\x10\\xec\\xeb=\\x96t\\xcc&\\x9d]\\xbdQY\\x95\\xfb\\xd4\\x93\\xc3\\xe1'"
```

What am I doing wrong? I know it seems easy, but it isn't in my case.

Comment: What is `single_account()`?

Comment: Please include the code of `single_account` class

Comment: @DanielRoseman - Its the result of a query from a sqlite3 db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it,

```
single_account = ([('test', ['b"sc\\x00\\x02\\xe2e\\x96\\x99\\xbd\\xd9!R+\\xdf\\x87\\xd6\\xe8\\x9b\\xa8\\xd2q\\x92z\\x8a\\xe6\\xdat\\xd2\\x81\\x0f\\xb4r\\x021\\x0c\\xdd\\x00\\xba\\xe0\\xa8\\x13L\\x17\\xe2.\\xdb\\x9e\\xbe\\x1bE\\x8e\\xfd\\xbd\\xe6?\'\\x08\\x8f&\\xa2\\xf4;\\x93\\xe2\\xb5\\xb3{4\\xe1\\xd8"', "b'sc\\x00\\x02\\x97\\xcb\\x86\\x9f\\x18O\\xca\\xa4\\xd8\\x85\\xbcZ\\xb5 \\xda\\x19\\xc9_\\xf9\\x086\\xbe\\xb4\\x06\\x14\\x1a\\xe2\\x7fH\\xfe\\x19\\xe51\\x02\\x1e\\x83\\xd0\\x97\\xc2QL\\xd6\\xcb\\x13\\x89\\x1b\\x8bhX\\xe1Q\\xac\\x83}?\\xe2\\xc9\\xc4\\x10\\xec\\xeb=\\x96t\\xcc&\\x9d]\\xbdQY\\x95\\xfb\\xd4\\x93\\xc3\\xe1'", "b'\\xa5\\xb2\\xa5\\x99\\x00\\x90\\xdc\\x0e'", 1])])

print  single_account[0][1][2]
```

The `single_account[3]` won't work because its just not one list or tuple you are trying to access.

`single_account[0]` will give the first and only element of your list which is a tuple.

`single_account[0][1]` will give the second element of your inner tuple which is a list.

And finally the `single_account[0][1][2]` gives you the third element of your list which is the element you want.

I hope though that you can get your query results in better way.